# EventSystem.Update() выделяет мусор

Tags: unity3d

На андроиде при каждом касании кнопки EventSystem.Update() выделяет 308 байт мусора. Это можно как-то исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мусор выделяет не система событий, а подписанные обработчики.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Убрал всех подписанных обработчиков, проблема осталась. Выяснилось, что аллокация происходит даже когда нажимаешь на обычную картинку с выключенным Raycast Target. Причем при профайлинге в эдиторе такой проблемы нет.